# center slider with css

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am using [Basic Slider](http://www.basic-slider.com/) for [my website](http://cabosgrillrestaurant.com/) but I don't know how I can center the slider, can you help me?

CSS STYLE FROM BASIC SLIDER:

```
ul.bjqs{position:relative;list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden; display:none;}display:none; margin:auto;}
li.bjqs-slide{position:absolute; display:none;}
ul.bjqs-controls{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;z-index:9999;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li a{position:absolute; margin:auto;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-next a{right:0;}
ul.bjqs-controls.v-centered li.bjqs-prev a{left:0;}
ol.bjqs-markers{list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%;}
ol.bjqs-markers.h-centered{text-align: center;}
ol.bjqs-markers li{display:inline;}
ol.bjqs-markers li a{display:inline-block;}
p.bjqs-caption{display:block;width:100%;margin:0;padding:2%;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add in css

```
#my-slider{
   margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @LuisLara You're totally Welcome .. Good Luck :)